# How to accelerate Vista after long time of using?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

Vista has been installed on my laptop for over 18 months, and it's taking long and longer to start the system(the time between I pressed the power button and when I can actually do things with it).

And Vista also get stuck quite often during daily use.

I know reinstall Vista will make things much better, but I wonder if there's any way other than reinstallation that can accelerate the system, especially the time used to start.

PS. I already have the minimal programs on startup, but it still takes too long to boot.

Comment: From my experience, a CLEAN re-install is the only guaranteed way to get back and keep that zippy feeling. Take the time to do a good backup, get your software keys in order and figure out which programs you want to re-install. From 15 years of MS Operating System experience, I really believe that windows has a "Half-Life." It gets half as fast as it used to be after a certain period of time.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of software likes to think it's the most important thing in the world, and forces itself into your startup folder. After a while, a lot of unimportant, rarely used programs accumulate there, so you have a bunch of bloatware trying to run on startup, and it just sits in the background wasting resources. Clearing it out speeds up things a LOT.

See [this](http://netsquirrel.com/msconfig/msconfig_win7.html.) Most everything can be removed except antivirus software and stuff you actually *want* running on startup. If you really want to doublecheck everything, there's this list [here](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/startups/). I wouldn't recommend toying around with anything outside the startup tab unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to an SSD or Solid-State Drive, and also upgrade and increase the amount of ram in your system, you computer's newfound speed make it seem just like new (if not better)

This is (of cource) assuming normal reasons for

Answer (score 0):

Clean Install Windows 7, a considerably better Operating System than Vista.

First, backup all your data to another HDD or External HDD.

Then use the Windows 7 Disk to boot into Windows 7 and use the easy to use installer to format your existing drive and install a fresh Windows. It's really easy!

I'm running Windows 7 off my 6-7 year old desktop (P4 3.2GH - 1G Ram) and it boots really quickly and feels really snappy.

I'd recommend it to anyone.

Comment: While I agree that Windows 7 is better than Vista, the question is about tuning-up Windows Vista. ... **Q:** "I spilled juice on my carpet. How do I wash it out?" **A:** "Oh, just replace your whole carpet with hardwood floor."

Comment: Point taken; however if that carpet really didn't match the Decor of the home; maybe this is a good excuse to upgrade.